# When did people first try to limit which weapons could be used in war?

Tags: warfare

The first example that I know is about chemical weapons after the first world war.

Comment: This question is too broad. You should do a google search before asking generic questions of this type.

Comment: The question is about a concrete aspect (weapons) in a concrete situation (war) about a concrete topic (ethics.)

Comment: The question is very similar to [this one](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/4312/1401).  Discussion of historical attempts to limit warfare seems in scope to me.  I've been struggling to find a clearer more elegant way to express the query, but I'm at a loss. I believe that there is a clearer way to ask the question, but I've got no suggestions that are superior to @QuoraFeans.  I also admit that I agree with Mr. Durden that the question would have been improved if it included evidence of prior research.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace:   yes both are related, although mine is limited by restricting the use of weapons (not entering into whether rape, pillage, killing civilians, salting the earth, submitting the prisoners to slavery is also acceptable.)

Comment: Can we restrict the question to "weapons"?  That might make it easier.  And can you show any google queries you did before posting?

Comment: yes, my original question was limited to weapons, not I edited it back to this limitation.

Comment: I tried to revise the question - once I realized that the question reduced to "What is the earliest Arms Control treaty", wikipedia answered the question.  Hat tip to @TylerDurden.   I will be serving myself a dish of stir fried crow today.

Answer (score 12):

- Even before the WW1, [The Hague Conventions (1899 and 1907)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hague_Conventions_of_1899_and_1907) worked, that, for example, forbade to use balloons for shooting or bombing or banned some rifle/cannon calibers.
- Crossbows were forbidden several time by Catholic Church or some kings. It was in Middle Ages.

  - [Henry VII., possession of crossbow forbidden](http://books.google.cz/books?isbn=0486139263)
  - [Pope Urban II banned the use of crossbows in 1096;](http://militaryhistorynow.com/2012/05/23/the-crossbow-a-medieval-wmd/)
  - [The use of bows or crossbows against Christians was forbidden by the second Lateran Council in 1139](http://books.google.cz/books?id=Hnq7AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=ancient%20arms%20limitations&source=bl&ots=YBcKzWtsEO&sig=RDJISJvKhpcsz19u1XkKZYA-HZk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0IaxU52TOcKJONTYgfAB&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=ancient%20arms%20limitations&f=false)
  - [To increase use of longbows, crossbows are banned in England](http://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofEngland/The-Longbow/)
- Far deeper into the past, in [Amphictyonic League](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphictyonic_League), the cutting of water supply as a war measure was forbidden. It was about mid-7th century BC.

Comment: I'm confused by the first sub-point under crossbows. Agincourt was fought in 1415. Henry VII was born in 1457 and became king in 1485.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: According to [pages 32-33 of the cited book](http://books.google.com/books?id=iiTEAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=isbn%3A0486139263&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q=henry&f=false), the act was introduced in 1508 (during the reign of Henry VII) but the author suggests that it was motivated by the success of the longbow in earlier battles, including Agincourt.  I am not sure what the number 46 signifies.